# get plot parameter from character vector

Tags: r

how can I define a color palette from a character vector in `plot()`?

```
pal1 <- c('red', 'green', 'blue')
pal2 <- c('yellow', 'brown', 'orange')

mypal <- c('pal1', 'pal2')

for(i in mypal){
   plot(1:3, col=i, pch=20, cex=5)
   }
```

I want to loop the same plot over a number of color palettes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping `get` around the `i` will do this... sorta.  But you'll only see the final plot unless you put in some wait or write the plots out to disk.

```
for(i in mypal){
   plot(1:3, col=get(i), pch=20, cex=5)
   }
```

or you can assign the values of `pal1` and `pal2` to your `mypal` as a list:

```
mypal <- list(pal1, pal2)
```